# jQuery Datatable is not a function when ajax reloading

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am using .net and knockoutjs. I have a Datatable successfully loading and populating with data via ajax. The problem I am seeing is when I try to add a call to reload the data with updated filter values. When I call a function that has the DataTable().ajax.reload() in it, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"

Why is the table successfully loading but any calls to the DataTables later are failing? I have done something similar previously and it worked so not sure what is going on exactly.

In the code below if you find the filter function you will see where I am exactly getting the error. It isn't the ajax.reload call itself that is failing, it is just trying to get the table by ID and do a .DataTable() on it.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Classrooms";
}

<div class="container" id="classrooms-div">
    <h1>Classrooms</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Create", "Classroom")"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Classroom</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div id="filters" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;border-radius: 5px;width:400px;margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="district" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">District</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control adminfield" id="district" data-bind="options: districts, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Select a District', value: selectedDistrict"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="school" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">School</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control adminfield" id="school" data-bind="options: schools, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Select a School', value: selectedSchool"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="conditions" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Research Condition</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control adminfield" id="conditions" data-bind="options: conditions, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Select a Research Condition', value: selectedCondition"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: filter">Filter</button>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="classrooms-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>District</th>
                <th>School</th>
                <th>Begin Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dashboardViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.classrooms = ko.observableArray();
        self.schools = ko.observableArray();
        self.districts = ko.observableArray();
        self.researchConditions = ko.observableArray();
        self.selectedSchool = ko.observable();
        self.selectedDistrict = ko.observable();
        self.selectedCondition = ko.observable();

        //when the district changes, update the schools
        self.selectedDistrict.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if(newValue != undefined && newValue != "")
            {
                //load the schools for this district
                self.LoadSchoolsByDistrict(self.selectedDistrict());
            }
        });

        self.LoadSchoolsByDistrict = function (district) {
            showSpinner(true);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadSchoolDropdownByDistrict", "School")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { districtId: district },
                success: function (response) {
                    showSpinner(false);
                    if (response.Success == true) {
                        self.schools(response.Entity);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(response.Message);
                        toastr.error(response.Message);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    showSpinner(false);
                    toastr.error("Error while loading schools!");
                    console.log(response.Message);
                }
            });
        };

        self.LoadDistricts= function () {
            showSpinner(true);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadDistrictDropdown", "District")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                    showSpinner(false);
                    if (response.Success == true) {
                        self.districts(response.Entity);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(response.Message);
                        toastr.error(response.Message);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    showSpinner(false);
                    toastr.error("Error while loading districts!");
                    console.log(response.Message);
                }
            });
        };

        self.filter = function () {
            var table = $('#classrooms-table').DataTable(); //THIS LINE FAILS HERE
            table.ajax.reload();
        };

        self.loadInitialData = function () {
            $('#classrooms-table').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '@Url.Action("LoadPagedClassrooms", "Classroom")',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data": function (d, settings) {
                        d.district = self.selectedDistrict();
                        d.school = self.selectedSchool();
                        d.condition = self.selectedCondition();
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            var button1 = '<a title="Click to View Details" href="@Url.Action("Details","Classroom")/' + full.id + '?role=admin">' + full.name + '</a>';
                            return button1;
                        }, "sortable": true
                    },
                    { "data": "grade" },
                    { "data": "districtName" },
                    { "data": "schoolName" },
                    { "data": "beginDate" },
                    { "data": "endDate" },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                        {
                            var button1 = '<a title="Details" href="@Url.Action("Details","Classroom")/' + full.id + '"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>';
                            var button2 = '<a title="Edit" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Classroom")/' + full.id + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>';
                            var button3 = '<a title="Delete" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Classroom")/' + full.id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                            return button1 + " | " + button2 + " | " + button3;
                        }, "sortable": false, "width": "65px"
                    },
                ]
            });
        }
    };

    var dashboardVM = new dashboardViewModel();
    dashboardVM.loadInitialData();
    dashboardVM.LoadDistricts();
    ko.applyBindings(dashboardVM, $('#classrooms-div')[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried:  `var table; self.loadInitialData = function () {table = $('#classrooms-table').DataTable({ //..so on`  and then `table.DataTable(); //THIS LINE FAILS HERE` ?  So, your initial instantiation of the datatable gets saved to a variable (that's within the scope of both the init and filter functions), and then you reference that variable in the filter function.  You may need to move your filter function so that it's below the function that does the initial load.

Comment: Could be related to jQuery. Any chance `self.filter` could be called without including jQuery? Or jQuery being included twice, with DataTables having it's own version? Or DataTables being included before jQuery? You could try adding `$.noConflict();` before `var table = $('#classrooms-table').DataTable();`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you're not getting the reference of the original DataTables Object with `var table = $('#classrooms-table').DataTable();`

Option [`retrieve`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve) on the original init of the Object should make it return the original instance:

```
self.loadInitialData = function () {
        $('#classrooms-table').DataTable({
            "retrieve": true,
            "processing": true,
            ...
```

Comment: I added the retrieve option to my initial init of the datatable and that wasn't enough to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this to work finally.

```
    self.loadInitialData = function () {
        self.table = $('#classrooms-table').DataTable({
            "retrieve": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [[0, "asc"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("LoadPagedClassrooms", "Classroom")',
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (d, settings) {
                    d.district = self.selectedDistrict();
                    d.school = self.selectedSchool();
                    d.condition = self.selectedCondition();
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        var button1 = '<a title="Click to View Details" href="@Url.Action("Details","Classroom")/' + full.id + '?role=admin">' + full.name + '</a>';
                        return button1;
                    }, "sortable": true
                },
                { "data": "grade" },
                { "data": "districtName" },
                { "data": "schoolName" },
                { "data": "beginDate" },
                { "data": "endDate" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        var button1 = '<a title="Details" href="@Url.Action("Details","Classroom")/' + full.id + '"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>';
                        var button2 = '<a title="Edit" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Classroom")/' + full.id + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>';
                        var button3 = '<a title="Delete" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Classroom")/' + full.id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                        return button1 + " | " + button2 + " | " + button3;
                    }, "sortable": false, "width": "65px"
                },
            ]
        });
    };

    self.filter = function () {
        self.table.ajax.reload();
    };
```